# Angular ngIf using parent checkbox checked condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm a bit stuck with my problem. I'm working on view like that:

[image]

I'm fetching data from API so I will have multiple options and suboptions. However I want suboption to appear only when parent checkbox is checked. I tried to use *ngIf:

```
 <ul *ngFor="let job of jobs; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{i}}" value="{{job.name}}"><label
   for="{{i}}">{{job.name}}</label>
  <ul *ngIf="CONDITION HERE">
   <li *ngFor="let child of job.children"><label><input type="checkbox"> 
    {{child.name}}</label></li>
   <li *ngFor="let child of job.children"><label><input type="checkbox"> 
    {{child.name}}</label></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

But I can't identify what condition could I use. Is there a simple solution to solve that?

@edit Let me clarify. I might have multiple options like that:

[image]

Using a flag won't work, because each parent options would have to use unique boolean variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of **template reference variable**. Assign a template variable to all repetitive parent input checkbox elements.

Use this variable to check the status of the checkbox (checked/unchecked) and based on this show/hide the children.

Please note that you will have to also use

```
(change)="true"
```

for parent checkbox. Without this the checked/unchecked property of the checkbox will not change.

Modify your template like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let job of jobs; let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ i }}" value="{{ job.name }}" (change)="true" #checkBox/><label
    for="{{ i }}"
    >{{ job.name }}</label
  >
  <ul *ngIf="checkBox.checked">
    <li *ngFor="let child of job.children">
      <label><input type="checkbox" /> {{ child.name }}</label>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let child of job.children">
      <label><input type="checkbox" /> {{ child.name }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3coln?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: A flag works only when I have 1 parent option, which is not a case.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: @Słowik - Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Add a checked property in your model, then based on if it is checked or not, display the child checkbox.

Ex (assuming your model is called Job)

```
export class Job {

isChecked: boolean = false; 

}
```

Then your ngIf would be `*ngIf="job.isChecked"`

Comment: But when I have multiple parent checkboxes I will have to create multiple booleans in class, right? I might have ~40 of them

Comment: Why? So you have a List<Job>, if you want inside of each job call you can add a reference to another so a job class can have a nested List of jobs for example you can call it subJobs : Job[]. SO then all you check for is "Is this job checked", then check if subJobs has a value and go from there

Answer (score 0):

```
<input [checked]="checkedMain" type="checkbox" id="{{i}}" value="{{job.name}}"><label
   for="{{i}}">{{job.name}}</label>
```

```
<ul *ngIf="checkedMain">
   <li *ngFor="let child of job.children"><label><input type="checkbox"> 
    {{child.name}}</label></li>
   <li *ngFor="let child of job.children"><label><input type="checkbox"> 
    {{child.name}}</label></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NgIf**

> A structural directive that conditionally includes a template based on
> the value of an expression coerced to Boolean.

You can just check if job exists.

```
<ul *ngIf="job"> //should do the job for you as it will be coerced to true if job exists.
```

Comment: Job will always exist. I need condition on wheter it is checked or not.

Comment: add a boolean property to job then.

Comment: I am using external API and Im not allowed to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way of achieving this would be to keep a isChecked property to track state of checkboxes for each option.

```
<div>
<ul *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ i }}" [(ngModel)]="option.isChecked" /><label
  for="{{ i }}"
  >{{ option.name }}</label
>
<ul *ngIf="option.isChecked">
  <li *ngFor="let subOption of option.subOptions">
    <label>{{ subOption }}</label>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</div>

options = [{ name: 'Type1', subOptions: [1, 2, 3], isChecked: false }];
```

Method 2: Incase if you do not want to modify the list of jobs/options

```
<div>
 <ul *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ i }}" [(ngModel)]="state[option.name]" /> 
<label
  for="{{ i }}"
  >{{ option.name }}</label
>
<ul *ngIf="state[option.name]">
  <li *ngFor="let subOption of option.subOptions">
    <label>{{ subOption }}</label>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </ul>  
</div>

options = [{ name: 'Type1', subOptions: [1, 2, 3]}];
state = {};
```

Comment: Please check the update answer. Method 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

suppose your list is like below from API

```
    this.list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'parent1',
    checked: false,
    children:["A","B","C"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'parent2',
    checked: false,
    children:["A","B","C"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'parent3',
    checked: false,
    children:["A","B","C"]
  }      
]
```

Your html code should be like below to hide/unhide the children based on parent state.

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of list">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked"/>{{item.title}}
 <ng-template [ngIf]="item.checked">
    <li *ngFor="let item1 of item.children">
    <input type="checkbox" >{{item1}}
  </li>
</ng-template>
</ul>
```